# Substitue string within string in shell

Tags: shell

How to substitue string withing string in shell

```
mode="create"
echo $mode
```

what i am trying is

```
echo ${CONFIG_Resource_$mode_val}
```

which gives me "bad substitution"

but this works fine

```
echo ${CONFIG_Resource_create_val}
```

Comment: What other variables do you have declared? I'm confused. What do you want to do? What is the desired output?

Comment: Basically I am reading yaml file and fetching the value. This works fine - ${CONFIG_Resource_create_val}... where "create" is mode" .My mode can be "create, build, run.... and so on.

Comment: so echo ${CONFIG_Resource_build_val}, echo ${CONFIG_Resource_run_val} should give me values.